# Nodejs Mongo date queries relative to database's date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

If I perform the following update from my NodeJS app:

```
db.collection('test').update({name: 'some_name'}, {$set: {update_time: new Date()}}, {w:1}, function(err) {
  console.log('successfully updated');
});
```

I believe it will use the NodeJS app's clock, is there a way to use the database's clock instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I generally wouldn't recommend based on that your server times **should** be synchronized, you could use [eval()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#eval)

```
db.eval("function(){ return new Date() }", function(err, result) {
  console.log( result );
});
```

That basically sends the JavaScript function to the server to execute and returns the result.

Read the docs and **use with caution**.